# Convert response to readable form

Tags: array, convert

> I am posting request to paypal using curl.

Please check following code

```
$url = 'https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp';
$request = array();

$request['USER'] = 'username' ;
   ---  sending other request fields like above --- 

$rd = '';

foreach ($request as $_key => $_val) 
 {
   $rd .= $_key . '=' . urlencode(mb_convert_encoding($_val, 'ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8')) . '&';
}

$output = array();

$curlSession = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $rd);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 90);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1);

$rawresponse = curl_exec($curlSession);
```

Now when curl execution is performed I am getting below reposne.

TIMESTAMP=2015%2d07%2d23T10%3a39%3a36Z&CORRELATIONID=61f4332aaf13e&ACK=Success&VERSION=90&BUILD=17485293

My issue is how to convert this in readable array form ?
Please help me

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you please give a little bit context? What are you querying with curl!? Which gateway? And what has this to do with magento? And please, edit the question and make a comment, that you have done it. DON'T comment the details please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say the variable `$response` contains what you get from paypal.

```
$decoded = urldecode($response);
```

will get you

```
TIMESTAMP=2015-07-23T10:39:36Z&CORRELATIONID=61f4332aaf13e&ACK=Success&VERSION=90&BUILD=17485293
```

further calling

```
$split = explode('&', $decoded);
```

will get you

```
Array
(
    [0] => TIMESTAMP=2015-07-23T10:39:36Z
    [1] => CORRELATIONID=61f4332aaf13e
    [2] => ACK=Success
    [3] => VERSION=90
    [4] => BUILD=17485293
)
```

You can even split further each element by `=` and get a key value pair.

**[Edit]**

Or better yet

```
$arr = array();
parse_str(urldecode($response), $arr);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($arr);
```

will get you

```
Array
(
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2015-07-23T10:39:36Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => 61f4332aaf13e
    [ACK] => Success
    [VERSION] => 90
    [BUILD] => 17485293
)
```